# Apex trigger - 2 custom objects - populate 1 field in objectA with a value (currency) from Object B

Tags: triggers, apex

I am a beginner on this apex endeavours. I can interpret code but I struggle on creating it.

So I just need to **understand how to create the subject explained trigger.**

**NOTE**: there is a condition that states for this to happen if the field is different from `0`, but it is not necessary.. as long as it updates it with the value on the `fieldb` on object `b` is enough.

If you can provide comments on all the steps for me to understand the why, that would be great

I came up with this, but it is obvious that it is not working:

```
trigger PopulateOrderValue on ObjectA__c (after insert)  {
   FieldA__c  A = Trigger.new
   ObjectB__c.FieldB__c != 0 
{
   A = ObjectB__c.FieldB__c
   update A;
    }
}
```

Comment: anyone? i could really use some help here

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there has to be some sort of relationship between the objects.

Then, you can capture that value and use it to form a mapping to update the fields on the other object.